# Windows update made VirtualBox VM disappear and now I can't enable shared folders or second screen in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Today I had Windows 10 update itself. I use Windows 10 as the VirtualBox VM host. When starting VirtualBox after the Windows update, I noticed VirtualBox didn't show my VMs anymore!

With the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161551/virtual-machines-virtualbox-disappear I managed to re-add my main Ubuntu VM.

However, after booting the resolution was ridiculous 640x480 or 800x600, very small. Practically unusable. The guest no longer resized when I resized the window. I managed to make the display larger by manually changing the resolution in Ubuntu guest, but it was a herculean effort as the display was so small the full "Settings" dialog didn't fit to the visible display.

I also noticed I cannot mount my shared folder. I also couldn't enable my second monitor.

How can I restore auto-resizing, shared folders and second monitor?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to restore the operation:

1. Reinstall VirtualBox to the newest version (I hadn't updated it for a long time in fear of breaking something in my setup)
2. Start the Ubuntu guest VM
3. Remove all Ubuntu virtualbox kernel modules:

   ```
   sudo apt remove virtualbox-guest-utils
   sudo apt remove virtualbox-guest-x11
   ```
4. Insert the Guest Addition CD (VirtualBox menu: Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image...)
5. Click the "Run" on the notification that opened and enter your password
6. After the installation is done, eject the CD and reboot.
7. After the reboot, you can mount shared folders, enable the second monitor, auto-resizing works too and as a bonus, shared clipboard works in both directions!